# Identifying the little disk operad with parenthesized braids

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, qa.quantum-algebra, operads

Let $D_2$ be the topological operad of little disks. This operad can be modelled "combinatorially" in terms of an operad of groupoids called $\newcommand{\PaB}{\mathbf{PaB}}\PaB$, the operad of *parenthesized braids*. An object of the groupoid $\PaB(n)$ is a complete parenthesization of a permutation of the symbols $\{1,...,n\}$, e.g.
$$ ((24)(13)5) \in \mathrm{ob} \,\PaB(5),$$
and morphisms are $n$-strand braids, such that the start- and endpoints of each strand are labeled by the same element of $\{1,...,n\}$. Composition in this operad is given by "cabling". The connection to the little disk operad is that one can quite easily write down a morphism of operads 
$$ \PaB \to \Pi_1(D_2),$$
where $\Pi_1(-)$ denotes the fundamental groupoid, such that $\PaB(n) \to \Pi_1(D_2)(n)$ is an equivalence of categories for all $n$.

If we denote by $N$ the composition of the nerve functor with the geometric realization, then $N\PaB$ is a topological operad.

*Fact: $N\PaB$ is equivalent to $D_2$, i.e. there is a zig-zag of operad morphisms between $N\PaB$ and $D_2$, each of which is arity-wise a weak equivalence.*

In the literature this fact is in several places proven by appealing to Fiedorowicz's recognition principle, see e.g. Dmitry Tamarkin, Formality of chain operad of little discs, Section 2. I don't understand why and I guess I am missing something: it seems to me that there is a much more direct argument. Indeed the map $\PaB \to \Pi_1(D_2)$ gives a homotopy equivalence 
$$N\PaB \to N\Pi_1(D_2),$$
moreover, the unit of the adjunction between $\Pi_1$ and $N$ gives a morphism 
$$D_2 \to N\Pi_1(D_2)$$
which is also an equivalence since $X \to N\Pi_1(X)$ is a homotopy equivalence for any $K(\pi,1)$-space, such as $D_2(n)$. What am I missing?

Comment: Have you looked at Severa's paper on Tamarkin's proof?  I think he constructs all of these equivalences explicitly.  In any case, +1 for the question.

Comment: Thanks, Theo! Did you mean his paper with Willwacher, "Equivalence of formalities of the little discs operad"? On the bottom of page 9 of their paper they give exactly the argument I give, which is encouraging.

Comment: In case someone wants a precise statement and proof, this is discussed at length in the book *Homotopy of Operads and Grothendieck-Teichmüller Groups* by Fresse, more precisely the statement is given in Proposition 6.2.2 ($\mathtt{PaB}$ is isomorphic to a suboperad of $\pi \mathtt{D}_2$). The unitary case (with nonempty arity zero) is also dealt with.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems to me that the operad morphism from **PaB** to $\Pi_1(D_2)$ works in positive arity  but does not respect composition with the $0$-ary operation on the object level.

Comment: Hi Paolo. It appears your mathoverflow accounts got duplicated. If you wish, you can try following the instructions at http://mathoverflow.net/contact/user-merge to merge your accounts. If that does not work, you can also make a request at http://mathoverflow.net/contact/other to merge your accounts. Some helpful information is also available at http://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/15/how-can-i-log-in-into-my-old-mathoverflow-account.

Comment: My pleasure, Paolo. It's good to have you back!

Comment: Thank you! This observation makes a lot of sense. For my purposes I am happy to ignore the 0-ary operation.